# Excel - Continue Sequential unique ID when duplicates skipped

Tags: excel, uniqueidentifier, sequential

I have a worksheet with reloading data. D2 assigns a Unique ID and then increases sequentially.  If duplicates are found they are given the same unique id.  Then the following row is then named out of sequence.
    For Instance in D2:

```
9mm-001
9mm-002
9mm-003
9mm-003 (Duplicate)
9mm-005 (Would like to read 9mm-004)
45 ACP-001
45 ACP-002
45 ACP-002 (Duplicate)
45 ACP-004 (Would like to read 45 ACP-003)
9mm-006 (Would like to read 9mm-005)
9mm-003 (Dupliate)
45 ACP-005 (Would like to read 45 ACP-004)
9mm-008 (Would like to read 9mm-006)
45 ACP-002 (Duplicate)
45 ACP-007 (Would like to read 45 ACP-006)
So on and so on but the data isn't sorted, can be random with repeats at any time
```

Here's the formula in D2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D$1:D2,MATCH(Q2,Q$1:Q1,0)),(TEXT(C2,0)&"-"&TEXT(COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2),"000")))
```

Hopefully this makes sense.  I know it's OCD and in the long run doesn't matter but I'd love to see a solution to this.  The formula increases the count even with the duplicates.  The unsorted random placement and different prefixes are throwing me off.  If I sort the formulas don't stay constant.  Any help is appreciated!

Sample: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v5y1ufxjiosmnap/My%20Reloading%20Data%20-%20Sample.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Are all the duplicates **sequential**??

Comment: The duplicates are indexed and matched and given the same name as the match.  Looking at the sample should help.  The duplicates could show up anywhere and that's making it difficult for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use sumproduct here.  By putting this formula in Cell D2, you should get the desired result as long as the data set is already sorted:

```
=C2&"-"&TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(--($C$2:$C$123=$C2),--($R$2:$R$123<>"Duplicate"),--(ROW($C$2:$C$123)<=ROW(C2))),"000")
```

The "--" simply converts the range to 1's (for true rows) and 0's (for false rows), and having multiple "--" is similar to an AND function.

Comment: If I sort then it throws all my load numbers off.  I can't sort the formulas, only the values.  It's almost, almost works, better than anything I've come up with.  In my sample file it works until the two duplicates at D:18:D19.  Those should stay 223 REM-001 but change to 223 REM_003.

Comment: How did you sort it?

Comment: I copy the whole sheet to another sheet and paste the values only.  Then it sorts fine as there are no formulas to screw up.